# Toggling html List items with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Using jquery...

I am attempting to click on a term or concept to see the definition appear (my list items). When I click on the definition, I want it to be replaced with the term or concept.

I attempted to use unique id's to separate each of the p & li to make them respond to the clicks individually. I added a href= "#" in my html to make each list item a link to click.

However, when I run the code the click operates on all four of the "java-showing" and "java-hiding" divs all at the same time. This results in the page only toggling between the first two list items "JavaScript (JS), & Operators" and the definition of JavaScript "An object-oriented...".

First why am I only getting one definition on click? I would expect 2...

If anyone can help me this would be great, I am incredibly new to Javascript, html, css.

//HTML

```
<body>
<ul>
 <div class ="java-hiding">
 <li id="li1" <a href="#"> JavaScript (JS)</a></li>
 </div>
 <div class ="java-showing">
   <p id="p1" <a href="#">An object-oriented computer programming language commonly used to create interactive effects within web browsers.</a></p>
 </div>
 <div class="java-hiding">
  <li id="li2" <a href="#">Operators</a></li>
  <div class ="java-showing">
    <p id ="p2" <a href="#">constructs which behave generally like functions, but which differ syntactically or semantically from usual functions</a></p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

//Java Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li#li1, p#p1, li#li2, p#p2").click(function() {
   $(".java-showing").toggle();
   $(".java-hiding").toggle();
});
});
```

///CSS

```
.java-showing { display:none; }
```

Comment: You haven't closed your opening `<li>` tags

Comment: and the `p` tags

Comment: Your li elements are not wrapped in a ul. Do you need them to be list items?

Answer (score 0):

Your Html is not well structured, since your class name is same the event will operates on all elements which is expected.

Also you don't have to put Id's for each element to achieve your functionality.

Are you looking for a behavior like this - [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gmv971r4/)

```
 <div class ="java-hiding">
    <li id="li1"><a href="#"> JavaScript (JS)</a></li>
 </div>
 <div class ="java-showing">
    <p id="p1">
      <a href="#">An object-oriented computer programming language commonly used to create interactive effects within web browsers.</a>
    </p>
 </div>
 <div class="java-hiding">
    <li id="li2"> <a href="#">Operators</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class ="java-showing">
    <p id ="p2">
      <a href="#">constructs which behave generally like functions, but which differ"#">constructs which behave generally like functions, but which differ syntactically or semantically from usual functions</a>
     </p>
  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
     $(this).parent().next().toggle(); 
  });
  $("p").click(function() {
     $(this).parent().toggle(); 
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to operate on all of the java-showing and java-hiding elements because they are classes. So they are are a collection. Also both of them are the selected to toggle in your click function.

This is what I think you want for your HTML.

```
<ul>
    <li id="li1" class ="java-hiding">
        <a href="#"> JavaScript (JS)</a>
    </li>
    <p id="p1" class="java-showing">
        <a href="#">An object-oriented computer programming language commonly used to create interactive effects within web browsers.</a>
    </p>
    <li id="li2" class="java-hiding">
        <a href="#">Operators</a>
    </li>
    <p id="p2" class="java-showing">
        <a href="#">constructs which behave generally like functions, but which differ syntactically or semantically from usual functions</a>
    </p>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you expected was to do something dynamic to display the content when you click, see the example I set up to help you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
   $(this).find("div").toggleClass('java-hiding');
});
});
```

```css
.java-hiding { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<ul>
 
 <li id="li1"><a href="#"> JavaScript (JS)</a>
 <div class="java-hiding">
   <p id="p1"> <a href="#">An object-oriented computer programming language commonly used to create interactive effects within web browsers.</a></p>
 </div>
 </li>

 

 <li id="li2"> <a href="#">Operators</a>
 <div class="java-hiding">
    <p id ="p2">
    <a href="#">constructs which behave generally like functions, but which differ syntactically or semantically from usual functions</a></p>
  </div>
 </li>
  
</ul>
```